# React component fails to render due to undefined property

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm a newbie to react, I'm using the create-react-app package, and express generator. I can't seem to be able to render the react component due to undefined property, which I can't see to understand why is it undefined? Here is my code:

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import PageContent from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const pageContent = new PageContent();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <pageContent.App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class PageContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            apiResponse: 'test test test'
        };
    }

    callAPI() {
        fetch("http://localhost:3127/testAPI")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: 'hello' }));
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.callAPI();
    }

    App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
              Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn React
            </a>
            <p className="App-intro">**{PageContent.state.apiResponse}</p>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default PageContent;
```

This is the error I get:

```html
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apiResponse' of undefined

App
src/App.js:39

  36 |       >
  37 |         Learn React
  38 |       </a>
> 39 |       <p className="App-intro">**{PageContent.state.apiResponse}</p>
  40 | ^    </header>
  41 |   </div>
  42 | );
```

Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use:

```
{this.state.apiResponse}
```

Edit: I noticed you're rendering the App method directly after creating an instance of the PageContent class. You don't need to do this. You can simply rename the `App()` method to be `render()`, then remove the `const pageContent = new PageContent();` and you can then render `<PageContent />` instead of `<pageContent.App />`.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried it, and got this error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined'

Comment: Oh I see you are referencing the App method directly. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! thank you so much! Can you please explain why it didn't work before and it does work now?

Comment: When you have `<PageContent />` react basically instantiates it for you because it's a class. If you have `<pageContent.App />` it is just a function and it will render it as a functional component, but there's no state associated with it.

Comment: Nice! So what I was missing is that's react instantiates the class for me upon rendering? Or at any case?

Comment: Yeah, you just need to define the `render()` class method.

Answer (score 1):

You are making 2 mistakes -

1. first write it as `{this.state.apiResponse`}
2. Your app.js file is not written properly, It should be something like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

export default class PageContent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            apiResponse: 'test test test'
        };
    }

    callAPI() {
        fetch("http://localhost:3127/testAPI")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: 'hello' }));
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.callAPI();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <p>
              Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
            <a
              className="App-link"
              href="https://reactjs.org"
              target="_blank"
              rel="noopener noreferrer"
            >
              Learn React
            </a>
            <p className="App-intro">{this.state.apiResponse}</p>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

after this import this PageContent in your index.js like this -

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import PageContent from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <PageContent />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: Hi, same as I've answered before: Unfortunately I tried it, and got this error: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined'

Comment: @BarakBensimhon write it like this. I've edited the answer.